# Manjaro Linux -- Can ONLY log in from root account

Tags: linux, root, crash, manjaro

First time Linux user. Treat me like a complete idiot.

Installed Manjaro on VMWare. I'm required to get into this whole Linux thing for college. First problem:

1. Created user account from root. (useradd test)
2. Gave 'test' a password. (passwd test, password, password, >confirmed)
3. Attempt to log in.

Manjaro looks like it's logging in. The screen flashes black. Then all of a sudden I'm back in the user login screen. This isn't right.

I do not have this issue with the root account. But for the purposes of my course, I do not want to be logged into the root account. It's not good practice either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `adduser` (friendlier interactive frontend to useradd) instead of pure `useradd`. `adduser` automatically creates home directory, adds user to needed groups etc.

Or use `useradd` with keys: `useradd -m -d /home/testuser -s /bin/bash -c "Test User" -U testuser`

Comment: adduser
> command not found

Comment: @Jojo so, use useradd with keys. 

`# useradd -m -g [initial_group] -G [additional_groups] -s [login_shell] [username]`


ArchWiki (Manjaro is Arch fork, right?) may be helpful with some questions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#User_management

Comment: @Jojo please, mark answer as best and question as answered. It will help to others with the same problem